# Copying location EXIF data from phone to camera photos?

Tags: metadata

Fairly straight forward question and a fairly common scenario I would imagine. I have taken photos with iPhone and digital camera of the same subjects and locations, most of these groups of photos have been put in folders like "Holiday in Dorset" or "Waterpark".

Is there a way to merge location data from iPhone photos (img*.jpg) to digital camera photos (DSC*.jpg) by folder? I have '000s of photos to do this with, so need to do this in as automated a way as possible. Happy to write batch scripts, just need to know best way to approach the problem and what tools to use.

Comment: "Fairly straight forward question and a fairly common scenario I would imagine." And one that has been asked here several times before. Have you searched the existing base of questions?

Comment: And, for the Android crowd: [How can I use an Android smartphone as GPS to geotag my photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/22341/15871)

Comment: I did. And no results. Search the text of my question title and see results

Answer (score 2):

- `exiftool` can be used to create a `gpx` file, as [Unapiedra describes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/42669/75526). In some Linux distributions, the `gpx.fmt` does not need to be created because it is already installed. After the `gpx` file has been created, `exiftool` can be called again to tag untagged files. Change filenames and time-zones as appropriate.

  ```
  exiftool -fileOrder gpsdatetime -p /usr/share/doc/libimage-exiftool-perl/fmt_files/gpx.fmt -ext jpg . > out.gpx

  exiftool -if 'not ($GPSLatitude or $GPSLongitude)' -geotag out.gpx '-geotime<${createdate}-00:00' -r -ext jpg  .
  ```
- If you have Google Location History turned on, you can download KML files from Google [Timeline](https://www.google.com/maps/timeline) or [Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/). Then use `exiftool` to tag your photos.

  ```
  exiftool -if 'not ($GPSLatitude or $GPSLongitude)' -geotag history.kml '-geotime<${createdate}-00:00' -r -ext jpg  .
  ```

Comment: Will give this a go assuming it works on Windows 10 and iPhone jpgs use those tags